# String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

Folks,
I get the String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget error in the below code. Mind you that I have a list with a named route inside and goes like this:

```
List tasks = [
      {
        'taskName': 'Delivery',
        'onPressed': () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/deliveryScreen');
        }
      },
];
```

The rest is a listview.builder:

```
Container(
            height: 70,
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 1.5,
                color: selectedTask == index ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: tasks[index]['onPressed'],
                title: tasks[index]['taskName'],
                trailing: Icon(
                  Ionicons.chevron_forward_outline,
                  color: selectedTask == index ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

How do I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
title: tasks[index]['taskName'],
```

With this:

```
title: Text(tasks[index]['taskName']),
```

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/title.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put your title proper way, refer [**`ListTile`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

```
       ListTile(
            onTap: tasks[index]['onPressed'],
            title: Text(tasks[index]['taskName'],),
            trailing: Icon(
              Ionicons.chevron_forward_outline,
              color: selectedTask == index ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
```